# Make ConstraintLayout components fill the whole display in a simple UI

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing a simple Android UI for a project as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVQnr.png

I wonder if it's possible to make all Constraint Layout's elements fill the whole display (I'm totally new to the Android world). Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tempSETTINGS"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/temperature"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/temperature"></Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/humSETTINGS"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/humidity"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/humidity"></Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hrSETTINGS"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/hr"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hr"></Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/empty1"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/presence"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/presence"></Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/empty2"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/accelerometer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/accelerometer"></Button>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/temperature"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Temperature Sensor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tempSETTINGS"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/humidity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Humidity Sensor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/humSETTINGS"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperature" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/hr"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Heart Rate Sensor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/hrSETTINGS"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/humidity" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/presence"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Presence Sensor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/empty1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hr" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/accelerometer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Accelerometer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/empty2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/presence" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="log"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/alarmSettings"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/alarmSettings" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/alarmSettings"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="alarm settings"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/log"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/accelerometer" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have another question. It is possible to change the key icon with a gear? I googled for it, as it isn't in android studio drawables, but i haven't found anything interesting.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didnt what you want from your question? It will be good if you can post the expected(dummy) UI design.

Comment: Re, your second question, you can have the gear icon and an 'unlimited' access to other icons on your app if you would add font awesome to your app. Its not really that hard to add now that android has native support for fonts, here is a link to a blog I wrote about that https://medium.com/@He_Is_Noel/fontawesome-on-android-apps-api-26-goodness-2c8a8dc399aa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use android:layout_weight to get fill the height. Will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Temperature Sensor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tempSETTINGS"
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/humidity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Humidity Sensor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/humSETTINGS"
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/hr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Heart Rate Sensor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hrSETTINGS"
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/presence"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Presence Sensor" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"></View>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/accelerometer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Accelerometer" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"></View>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_vertical">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/log"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="log" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/alarmSettings"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
           android:text="alarm settings" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks man, you really made my day. It's exactly what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible it depends what dimensions you want the object to fill though. As to how you would implement it.

For example if you want your button to extend edge to edge but only horizontally you need to fix those properties. As an example take your:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tempSETTINGS"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/temperature"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/temperature"></Button>
```

To make it fill the screen horizontally you should be able to do something like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tempSETTINGS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/temperature"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"></Button>
```

Alternatively you can define a layout weight like 1.0 in the Linear Layout then set them for each child in their own XML. The amount each child contributes to the total defines the percentage of the screen they cover. This also scales well over different screen sizes and aspect ratios.

As for setting the image you can set it to whatever you want just add it to drawable and assign the appropriate reference. If you can't find it one of Google's Android images I suggest taking a look at [Material.io](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline). It will also let you get the different dpi variants for each of the assets, as well as a black or white version. Then use the same properties like opacity as before.

Comment: Thank you too, i opted for ur second solution as Edu Romero said.